# iOS Dynamic Form in UITableViewCells, Retrieve Values

Tags: ios, iphone, forms, uitableview, dynamic

I have been searching and reading all over but couldn't find any conclusive method to achieve what I want to and hope to find help here...

I have a UITableView which allows the user to add multiple Flavours and Percentages to a Recipe. I have implemented the method to add or delete rows of Flavours with a custom Cell / Nib  and it works perfectly well.

**The issue I'm facing now, is how to retrieve the values the user has provided per added row**.

(Edit for Clarity: My problem is not the populating of data, but only the dynamic reading of all data so I can save it)

I do manage to get the values for the visible rows (I do understand how the Reuseidentifier and the Tableview works, per se that for memory management's sake, iOS only keeps track of the visible rows), but not the hidden ones.

I assume in theory that I have to create an Array of Cells outside of 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' which maintains all cells. But then I'm facing another conceptual problem that my custom Nib / cell doesn't show.... basically:

- How can I then use / register a nib without using the dequeingidentifier
- Or in General, how can I solve the overall problem to be able an read all user entered values per row

[image: Screenshot TableView]

Here the code I'm using within my cellForRowAtIndexPath. As mentioned adding and remove cell works like a charm, that isn't the issue...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

RecipeFlavourTableViewCell *cell;
int section = (int)indexPath.section;

if(section==0)
    return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


if(!cell){
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RecipeFlavourCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;
```

}

I have seen some Libraries doing it (e.g. XLForm) but do not understand (also when checking their sources) how they iterate through the values and overcome this dequeuing problem...

Any help is highly appreciated

EDIT 2: here the code I'm using to iterate through the cells in order to save the data, but as said I can only iterate through the visible cells:

```
- (IBAction)saveRecipe:(id)sender {

NSInteger dynamicRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:1];

    for (int i=0; i<dynamicRows; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:1];
        RecipeFlavourTableViewCell *cell = (RecipeFlavourTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(cell.flavour.text);
    }
```

}

Comment: Where do you keep information that will be populated into the table?

Comment: as mentioned below, my issue is not the populating but the reading and saving of the data the user entered

Comment: This is the classic kind of problem you run into when you don't separate the model from the view very well... I think one can overdo the whole MVC architecture but this is where it's a very good thing. You really want to have an underlying data model that is used to populate the cells (initially empty, yes), and a separate controller that maintains the current data as entered by the user, and hooks in the UI to continually update the model when new values are entered.

Comment: @RobP I finally came to a similar conclusion, see my answer below

Comment: The difference I am suggesting is that you don't keep an around an array of UITableViewCells. You have a component whose job is to keep around a bunch of Recipe Data in your own useful abstract form -- as an NSArray, perhaps, initially. You populate UITableViewCells from that data, and editing cells flows back to change that data. Then the underlying data representation can move directly to living in CoreData instead of an NSArray, and all the UI-related code does not have to change.

Comment: @RobP well worth putting some thoughts into that... thanks for the cue. To be honest, I'm not yet at the stage of populating the data back into the fields (but rather create the initial datasets), but I can well imagine that your train of thoughts applies when I get there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 2 days of searching I finally came up with a solid solution. In case someone bumps into the same problem of dynamic forms with a tableview, here the solution:

As we understand, what ever cell is created in cellForRowAtIndexPath, it only persists as long as it is displayed. As soon as you scroll and the cell disappears, it gets automatically thrown out of memory. This behaviour makes it impossible to iterate through all cells at a later stages.

The steps to follow in order to make it work are as follows:

**Preparation**

- Create an NSObject with all properties you want to persist in one form cell (-> cellObject)
- In the ViewDidLoad of your controller create a NSMutableArray which will contain the cellObjects (-cellsArray)
- Add as many cellObjects to the cellsArray as you initially want to appear in the Tableview
- In numberOfRowsInSection return the count of you cellsArray
- In the cellForRowAtIndexPath build your cells as usual BUT add a Textfield Delegate (self) to every Textfield in a cell

**TextField Delegate**

Implement:

```
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

and update your cellsArray Objects every time a Textfield ends editing. Per se, get the cellObject for the row and edit the properties with the value of the TextField

**Add Row**

When ever you add a row, just add an empty cellObject to your cellsArray and use the beginUpdates / insertRowsAtIndexPaths / endUpdates on your tableView (NOT reloadData as the already typed in data would get lost). Also add the following at the very beginning of your addRow method, as you want to make sure that if the user adds a row while editing a textfield, the latter gets persisted as well:

```
 [self.view.window endEditing: YES];
```

**Remove Row**

Same as Add Row just reverse, remove the cellObject from your cellsArray and use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths on your tableView

**Save Data**

Now comes the trick: since you ought to always persist your data when a field ends editing mode, there is one case you need to cover: What if the user pushes "Save" when the focus is set on one TextField? Well at the very beginning of your Save Action insert the following:

```
 [self.view.window endEditing: YES];
```

This make sure the the textFieldEndEditing will be triggered one last time for the current textField and that its data will also be persisted.

Finally iterate through your cellsArray and do whatever you want with it (validate, save etc)...

That's it, hope this can help anyone else as I couldn't find any valuable explanation anywhere else...

Comment: It's always a good practice to assign a unique integer to `tag` property to each `UITextField` in TableView. This way you can easy differentiate which `textField` has end editing.

Answer (score -1):

Lets assume that you have an NSArray and that it contains data you want to show. Your code should look something like this:

```
// Add this property to the class and fill it in with data you want to show
@property NSArray flavourElements;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RecipeFlavourTableViewCell *cell;
    int section = (int)indexPath.section;

    if(section==0)
        return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    if(!cell){
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RecipeFlavourCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        // At this point your cell is ready for showing
        // And you can change values in it by getting element from array that contains data
        cell.flavorTextField = flavourElements[indexPath.row].flavour
        cell.precentageTextField = flavourElements[indexPath.row].precentage        
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;

}
```

I wrote a code for accessing elements without knowing what you actually have, so you will need to adjust it a little bit to fit your app.

Comment: your example describes how to populate data into the tableview, but that is not my problem. My issue is that when the user opens the view, there is no data yet (basically he creates a new object) and he needs to supply data. So what I need is to be able to iterate through all the rows / data so I can save it to Core Data

Comment: Okay, so you little missed with code. The answer above shows you how to get data in table, but it's assumed that you get it in array. Give me more on what's in in Core Data so I can write you some code.

Comment: Thanks for your offer @TheLittleHawk, the point is there is no Core Data yet, it has to be created in that form. In short, the user creates a new Core data entry in that very form and then pushes save. So my issue is to go through these dynamic rows (note he can add a row with the Plus button in the header) and save them into core data

Comment: I added another piece of code to show how I currently try to save the data, but as mentioned I can only iterate through the visible cells and not the hidden ones

Comment: Aham, okay. Have you tried template Master-Detail project from Xcode? It you select Core Data checkbox at start, it will bring you all code that is needed for creating database (SQLite) and saving items to it. Also it has save over + with delete button for each row. You can copy/paste that code into your project to get start with.

Comment: you are completely missing my problem... its about "dynamic form" in a tableview, nothing else

Comment: Okay, I do get you now, I 'll post some code later on fetching data from all cells visible and invisible Ones. I'll delete this irrelevant answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66267/discussion-between-ibesuf-and-thelittlehawk).